# Upgrade docker-compose permission denied

Tags: 16.04, permissions, docker

I am trying to upgrade docker-compose since with the current version I get some error when running a .yml file. Here my current situation:

```
$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker
$ which docker compose
/usr/bin/docker-compose

$ ls -al | grep docker
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    13511128 Feb 28 09:02 docker
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         336 Dez 11  2015 docker-compose
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    11314960 Feb 28 09:01 docker-containerd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    10464424 Feb 28 09:01 docker-containerd-ctr
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     1976648 Feb 28 09:01 docker-containerd-shim
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    39473368 Feb 28 09:03 dockerd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      862296 Feb 28 09:01 docker-init
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     2573840 Feb 28 09:01 docker-proxy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     8195464 Feb 28 09:01 docker-runc
```

When tryint to update docker-compose from https://github.com/docker/compose/releases. The output of the command:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

gives me:

```
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

I am also sudoing the command. Why is that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is that the `sudo` will be execute only on the `curl` part of the command, and not on the `>` part of the commeand.

You can cause `sudo` to run on both parts of the command in the following way:

```
sudo bash -c "curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/bin/docker-compose"
```

The simple solution might be:

1. Download the file

   wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m`
2. use `sudo` to place it in the right location

   sudo mv docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` /usr/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

you need sudo access after > this also Just change your command like below. use tee command with | pipe.

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` |sudo tee /usr/bin/docker-compose
```